How to Extend Blazor WebSocket Buffer on WebAssembly Hosted Solution
I have a blazor WebAssembly Hosted Solution (.net 6) and am having issues with a RadzenFileInput.  The error is that the fileSize is to large. I am using this as a photo upload and the file size of this photo is 5761KB as a png.  Radzen support has suggested increasing the buffer size as shown here
https://github.com/radzenhq/radzen-blazor/blob/master/RadzenBlazorDemos.Server/Program.cs#L17
However, does not look like I am running the same version of Blazor as them.  My Server Program.cs is as follows
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .Enrich.WithProperty("InstanceId", Guid.NewGuid())
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Origin", "Server")
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting up");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }

    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}

I have attempted to add the same within the Server StartUp.cs within the Configure Method however AddRazorComponents() doesnt exist.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Register the Datacontext and Connection String
    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
        options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
        .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
    );

    services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

    //Sets up the default Asp.net core Identity Screens - Use Identity Scaffolding to override defaults
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

                //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:IssuerUri").Value))
                //{
                //    options.Tokens.AuthenticatorIssuer = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:IssuerUri").Value;
                //}
            })
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

    //Associates the User to Context with Identity
    services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:IssuerUri").Value))
        //{
        //    options.IssuerUri = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:IssuerUri").Value;
        //}
    }).AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, DataContext>(options =>
    {
        options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
        options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
    });
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove(JwtClaimTypes.Role);

    //Adds authentication handler
    services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();

     services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    //Send Grid Email Sender
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISendGridEmailSender, SendGridEmailSender>();
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
    {
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(5);
        o.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
    services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o => o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3));

    //Register Radzen Services
    services.AddScoped<DialogService>();
    services.AddScoped<NotificationService>();
    services.AddScoped<TooltipService>();
    services.AddScoped<ContextMenuService>();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}

I have tried adding
services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddHubOptions(o =>
{
    o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
});

and
services.Configure<HubOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10* 1024 * 1024;
});

Both do not fix the issue.   Is there a way to increase the buffer size on a webassembly hosted solution?

Blazor WebAssembly apps do not use SignalR between then browser and the .NET runtime. So that it doesn't make sense to set Hub Options to increase the buffer size. And just like what you can see, the demo are used after .AddServerSideBlazor() or .AddInteractiveServerComponents(). But your app is blazor wasm.

So how do you increase the buffer size with a blazor wasm

here the buffer size is for web socket connection between client and server, I'm afraid you need to manually add asp.net core signalr into your blazor web assembly app and then you could try to add the buffer size.
